# 50's or 60's movie/serial with invaders and a "glubbahd glubbahd" machine

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This was 1950's/60's movie/serial. It was about a young boy around 12 years old. He was named Timmy, Bobby, Johnny or one of those "-y" names. He had a best friend, also with a "-y" name, along with a mom and dad. There was also an old white-haired professor rocket scientist and a rocket ship ready to launch.

The invaders at a domed building with the "glubbahd glubbahd" (the sound made by the machine mixing) machine that is a black tar-like substance into which people are thrown.

The Army saves the day by blowing up the building using bazookas and the rocket is launched.

Comment: Is it actually called the 'glubbahd glubbahd' machine  or is that just your name for it?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is [Invaders_from_Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1953_film)), [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045917/),
[Full movie](https://tubitv.com/movies/536480/invaders-from-mars)

> Late one night, youngster David MacLean is awakened by a loud
> thunderstorm. From his bedroom window, he sees a large flying saucer
> descend and disappear into the sandpit area behind his home. After
> rushing to tell his parents, his scientist father goes to investigate
> David's claim. When his father returns much later in the morning,
> David notices an unusual red puncture along the hairline on the back
> of his father's neck; his father is now behaving in a cold and hostile
> manner. David soon begins to realize that something is very wrong: he
> notices that certain townsfolk are acting in exactly the same way.
> Through his telescope, David sees child neighbor Kathy Wilson suddenly
> disappear underground while walking in the sandpit. David flees to the
> police station for help and is eventually placed under the protection
> of health-department physician Dr. Pat Blake, who slowly begins to
> believe his crazy story.

So for the kids we have David and Kathy (partial match).
Mom's name is Mary.

David has his parents, we see them most of the movie.
At the very beginning David's father falls into the something like a quicksand, with the sound that could be that "glubbahd glubbahd" (on tubitv it is at about 7:55).

Other people fall into that "pit", with the same sound accompanied.

Rocket ready for launch:
[image]

Some **red** substance, that could look black on a BW TV (timestamp 1:18:12) (could be match for the "black tar-like substance", posting here grayscale image):
[image]

In the end army arrives and starts shelling the place:
[image]

Charge set, it is about to blow:
[image]

Some troops get into the "pit" and "Army saves the day":
[image]

Launch:
[image]

Badum:
[image]